# Is it possible to serve images from Firebase static hosting?

Tags: image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple Firebase web application which is hosted on Firebase static hosting service where you can upload a picture with some textboxes and it gets stored in the Firebase realtime database like this:

```
{
    name: string,
    description: string,
    picData: base64 string
}
```

Now I would like to serve this image via a HTTP Get request. Is that even possible?
Something like: http://myawesomewebsite.com/getImage?name=x
The same like https://picsum.photos/ does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to serve content from the Firebase Realtime Database on a GET request, you will have to extend the functionality of Firebase Hosting using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) or [Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run).

The [*Connect Functions to Hosting*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#connect_functions_to_hosting) section explains the steps required to serve a "bigben" page that could quickly be adapted to decode the base64 in your database and return the data. Be wary that you must also specify the image's mime type (e.g. image/png, image/jpeg) when serving the image which you don't currently store in your database.

While possible, I would recommend storing your images in [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start) instead. This will help keep track of meta data such as sizes, mime types and upload times whilst not clogging your database with files stored in Base64. Images stored on Firebase storage can also be retrieved via a GET request by the client SDKs or served from a Cloud Function.

Comment: Ohh the Firebase Storage is absolutely the way to go. I specify the name and location of the image and when I have uploaded it, it is just a matter of making a get request to that location. Brilliant!